# remove a part of url using php

Tags: php

**I have this url :**

```
http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg
```

and need to convert to :(remove all url before 1)

```
1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg
```

**EDIT:**

`http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/` is dynamic So Maybe : `http://localhost/uploads/files/`

how do can I convert this url using php?

Comment: Why you did not use `str_ireplace` for it?

Comment: maybe the `1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg` is dynamic too. Maybe it is `1/2/3/4/5/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg` next Tuesday.

Comment: @NewCod3r : Are you sure the '1' will be there??

Comment: @NewCod3r: What will be fixed always in the link?? Anything??

Comment: @SubinThomas: yes, `1` is author id and always there.

Comment: @NewCod3r Please check my answer. If author id changes, it will not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the rules/conditions you need but this is a way:

```
$url = parse_url('http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg');
echo str_replace('/cms/uploads/files/', '', $url['path']);
```

UPDATE:

If `images`is static:

```
$url = parse_url('http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg');
preg_match('/[0-99999]\/.*/', $url['path'], $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: `1` and/or `images` are static?

Comment: only `1` is static. `1` is author id and other is dynamic

Comment: good work But if author id = `99999+1` your method is good way?

Comment: I don't know how many digits you need, you can extend it for example `[0-9]{12}` allows 12 digits to be there

Comment: And `preg_match`  work in` PHP 5.6 +` ?! or we need add `^` .

Comment: Yes `preg_match` exists since PHP 4.x http://php.net/manual/it/function.preg-match.php

Comment: `matches[0]` not work in php array see this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296447/php-array-filter-send-empty-value

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to get whatevers after the host (in this case localhost) and then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the path, [slice an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back:

```
$str = "http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg";
$parsed_url = parse_url($str);
echo implode("/", array_slice(explode("/", $parsed_url['path']),4));
```

Comment: In that case do `implode("/", array_slice(explode("/", $parsed_url['path']),-3));` which will only take the last 3 items in path (1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg)

Comment: only `1` is static. `1` is author id and other is dynamic . `-3` not work n my case

Comment: `$matches = array(); preg_match('/\/[0-9]+\/.*$/', $parsed_url['path'], $matches);` after that `$matches[0]` will have what you need

Comment: You can also do `preg_match('/.*(\/[0-9]+\/.*)$/', $parsed_url['path'], $matches);` if there is a chance of having /1/3/4/5 and you need only /5/... Your result will be in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution may be;

```
$basepath = 'http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/';
$url = 'http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg';
if (strncmp($basepath, $url, strlen($basepath)) == 0 ) {
    $result = substr($url, strlen($basepath));
} else {
    $result = false;
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: that is why, it is assigned to a variable. Use anything you want as value; like
$basepath = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST]. '/cms/uploads/files/';

Answer (score 0):

Try this, dynamic content with '/1/' will work perfectly

```
$str = "http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/1/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg";
//url as string
$pos = strpos($str,'1');    //position of first '1' in url
$len = strlen($str);    //length of url string
$str1 = substr($str,$pos,($len-$pos));  //substring from '1' onwards
```

There are few drawbacks too. If the '1' occurres before , i mean url =  "http://localhost/**cms1**/uploads/files/1/images, it will give wrong result.
If you use dynamic author id, instead of 1, save author id as a variable and insert in strpos(). The below one will be more accurate and you can use dynamic authorID too.

```
$str = "http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/1/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg";
//url as string
$authid = 1;    //author id
$searchstring = '/'.$authid.'/';    // create a search string  '/1/'
$pos = strpos($str,$searchstring);  //position of first '/1/' in url
$len = strlen($str);    //length of url string
$str1 = substr($str,$pos+1,($len-$pos));    //substring from '1' onwards
```