# php array_filter send empty value

Tags: php, arrays

**I have this array**:

```
Array (
    [0] => http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/hd-allpaper-40.jpg 
    [1] => http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/images/IMG_6217.JPG
    [2] =>
)
```

Now with this code, serialize data and insert to my database :

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST['image_url']) as $image_url) {

    if(!empty($image_url)) {

        $url = parse_url(array_shift($_POST['image_url']));
        preg_match('/[0-99999]\/.*/', $url['path'], $matches);

        $value['gallery_data'] = serialize((array(
                                   array_filter($matches[0]), 
                                   array_values($_POST['image_title']), 
                                   array_values($_POST['image_alt'])
                                 )));

        print_r $value['gallery_data'];

    }

}
```

But when i `print_r $value['gallery_data'];` ***matches[0]*** send empty value.

EDIT : when replace `$matches[0]` with `$_POST['image_url']` my code worked true.

var_dump(matches[0]):`string(28) "1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg" string(21) "1/images/IMG_6217.JPG"`

how do fix this problem ?!

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($matches[0]);` if you take the output from the source code

Comment: @Rizier123: when replace `$matches[0]` with `$_POST['image_url']` my code worked true. I think my problem with `$matches[0]`.

Comment: you change the array by shifting inside the loop by this line :  $url = parse_url(array_shift($_POST['image_url'])); why u do not take the $image_url

Comment: @Rizier123:`string(28) "1/images/hd-wallpaper-40.jpg" string(21) "1/images/IMG_6217.JPG"`

Comment: Um... `[0-99999]` ...that's ...not right.